# Rolling 20 workday revenue

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Currently visualizing sales for the past 30days, but looking to switch it in to the past 20 workdays instead, I've got workday column up and running in datetable, so ideally id want to use a filter of workday=1 and grab the 20 newest rows?

```
    Sales 30d = 
    CALCULATE([Sales], 
    FILTER(
        ALL(d_dates[date]),
    d_dates[date]
        >TODAY()-30))
```

This is what im using to show revenue for past 30 days, what'll i need to change?

Comment: Please put some sample data from your source table and datetable.

Comment: @mkRabbani don't know how to link pictures in here, but can't imagine what you would need the tables for, as i'm simply looking for a way to filter using a column in datetable.

d_dates has everything you can imagine, date (xx.xx.xxxx), no of month, no of day, but most importantly column called workday which i'm looking to use, I want to SUM of X for last 20 dates where workday = 1.

If needed i'll try and get pictures of the data

Answer (score 0):

```
VAR Last20Workdays = 
selectcolumns(
    TOPN(
        20,
        FILTER(
            d_dates,
            d_dates[date] < TODAY() 
            && d_dates[workday] = 1
        ),
        d_dates[date],
        DESC
    ),
    "WorkDay", 
    d_dates[date]
 )
```

This worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this below measure-

```
slaes_last_20_days = 

VAR today = TODAY()

VAR selected_date_min =
MINX(
    TOPN(
        20,
        FILTER(
            ALL(d_dates),
            d_dates[date].[Date] <= today 
                && workday = 1
        ),
        d_dates[date].[Date],
        DESC
    ),
    d_dates[date].[Date]
)

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    [Sales],
    FILTER(
        ALL(d_dates),
        d_dates[date].[Date] >= selected_date_min
            && workday = 1
    )
)
```